# How can I call MemberwiseClone()?

Tags: c#, object, clone

I'm confused about how to use the `MemberwiseClone()` method. I looked the example in MSDN and they use it trough the `this` keyword.

Why I can not call it directly as other objects' methods like `GetType()` or `ToString()`? Another related method that does not appear is `ShallowCopy()`.

If they are part of the Object class why can't I see them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `MemberwiseClone()` function is `protected`, so you can only access it through a qualifier of your own type.

Comment: damn i still don't get it. For example look the DerivedPoint example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bcd5672a(VS.80).aspx , the derived class access directly the protected inherited members, with the MemberwiseClone i can't do that

Comment: @voodoomsr: By "I don't get it" are you saying that you don't understand what "protected" means, or that you don't understand why the method is protected?

Comment: @Eric look the example in the url that i put. In the DerivedPoint instance they access inherited protected members directly. I don't get it why that is fine and what i try to do not.

Comment: @voo: You can do that with `MemberwiseClone`, **as long as the qualifier is of your type**.

Comment: @Slacks, can you give me an example please?, i don't understand the bold phrase :(

Comment: @voo: The _qualifier_ is the object you call the method on (eg, `this`).  Its compile-time type must be the class your method is in.

Comment: Works: `new MyClass().MemberwiseClone()`.  Doesn't work: `new UnrelatedClass().MemberwiseClone()`.

Comment: @Voodoomsr: SLaks is right. The reason is that "protected" means "only accessible within this type or a subtype of this type". Suppose you have a protected method on object. Suppose a subtype of object, Animal, overrides that protected method. Now suppose another subtype of object, Tricycle, tries to access the method on Animal. That's not legal; even though Tricycle is a subtype of object, Tricycle is *not a subtype of Animal*.

Comment: let me see if i understand. The object that access the method is the object that contains the call(the complete sentence), not the object using to retrieve the method definition, i.e. MyClass().MemberwiseClone() is going to work only if as a sentence is contained in the same MyClass or in a subtype of it. I think that  the reason of my misunderstanding is that i tought that MyClass().PrivateMembercall() would work always because MyClass is efectivelly the same class, ignoring where the sentence really occurs. I'm ok now?

Comment: @voodoomsr: The rules for protected access are a bit complicated, yes. Summing up. Suppose base class B has a protected method M. B has derived classes, D and E. A call made from inside D is of the form r.M(). The compile-time type of r is required to be D or a type derived from D. r's type may not be E, because E.M is not accessible from D; D does not get to call E's protected member. r's type may not be B, because then r *might* be an E at runtime.

Comment: @voodoomsr: These articles might help further: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/protected/

Comment: @Eric, @Slacks thanks both, i think i finally get the idea, :D

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example, this is what I did and no problems so far.

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public T ShallowCopy<T>() where T : ModelBase
    {
        return (T)(MemberwiseClone());
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
var cloned = User.ShallowCopy<User>();
```

Comment: This method isn't really generic. This is a glorified cast. You could write this and it would compile: `var cloned = user.ShallowCopy<Car>();`  but crash at execution time because a user is not a car.